# zed graph x axis labels

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, zedgraph

I am trying to loop through my datatable column sdescr and use the text in the columns as the labels of my x axis, but it isnt working i am getting this error

> Value of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of
>   String)' cannot be converted to
>   '1-dimensional array of String'.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To myCurve1.Points.Count - 1
        Dim pt As PointPair = myCurve1.Points(i)
        ' Create a text label from the Y data value   
        Dim text As New TextObj(pt.Y.ToString("f0"), pt.X, pt.Y + 0.1, CoordType.AxisXYScale, AlignH.Left, AlignV.Center)
        text.ZOrder = ZOrder.A_InFront
        text.FontSpec.Angle = 90
        myPane.GraphObjList.Add(text)


        Dim labels As New List(Of String)

        For Each row As DataRow In tablegraph.Rows
            labels = row.Item("SDESCR")
        Next row

        myPane.XAxis.Scale.TextLabels = labels
        myPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Text
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the code to get the labels out of your For Next loop that is creating points.

Which means this

```
    Dim labels As New List(Of String)          
    For Each row As DataRow In tablegraph.Rows             
    labels = row.Item("SDESCR")         
    Next row          

    myPane.XAxis.Scale.TextLabels = labels         
    myPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Text
```

Now, outside of the loop plotting points, you need to go through your DataTable

Please look at the error you're getting... The List of String can't be converted into a string array.  Those objects aren't equivalent.

One option would be to do something like this (after your loop to plot points)

```
Dim labels(tablegraph.Rows.Count - 1) as String

For i As Integer = 0 To tablegraph.Rows.Count - 1
     labels(i) = tablegraph.Row(i).Item("SDESCR")
Next

myPane.XAxis.Scale.TextLabels = labels         
myPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Text
```

I don't have Zed here on this computer, so I haven't checked this in Visual Studio, but this should give you a very decent direction.